# Outlook Printing Issue

Tags: microsoft-outlook, printing, calendar

Outlook 2016.

When printing a calendar, the print is not rendered properly. It is as if all the data is missing.

I've tried turning off add ons, recreating mail profile, resetting views.

Has anyone seen this before?[image]

Comment: Use the Print Options button to verify the date range and specific pages to print.

Comment: We can  reset print options via clicking Print Options > Define Styles > Reset.

Comment: Changing the ranges in Print Options does not impact this.

Comment: Resetting the Print Options did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Press Print Options.
Press Page Setup.
Go to the Paper tab.
Ensure Paper Type is set appropriately.

This solved it for me.